# OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager Failed to load project on Linux

Tags: linux, .net-core, visual-studio-code, manjaro, omnisharp

I am learning C# on my Manjaro Linux Notebook. I tried to install the ms-vscode.csharp extension, but when opening any .NET Core project I get the following Error Message:

> Some Projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more
>   information.

I tried to set the `"omnisharp.path"` option in the VS Code settings to `"latest"` but it did not change anything.

I am using version 1.21.8 of the extension and version 1.40.2 of VS Code.

Any ideas how to solve the issue?

VS Code Error Log:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 12/3/2019, 1:16:18 PM
    Target: /home/marco/dev/big-number

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: /home/marco/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.8/.omnisharp/1.34.8/run
    PID: 9119

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on manjaro 0.0 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 16.3 - "/home/marco/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.8/.omnisharp/1.34.8/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/marco/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.8/.omnisharp/1.34.8/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.dll'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.3 - "/home/marco/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.8/.omnisharp/1.34.8/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            MSBuildToolsPath = /home/marco/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.8/.omnisharp/1.34.8/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
            CscToolPath = /home/marco/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.8/.omnisharp/1.34.8/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
            BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = /home/marco/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.8/.omnisharp/1.34.8/omnisharp/.msbuild
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '/home/marco/dev/big-number'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in '/home/marco/dev/big-number'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/home/marco/dev/big-number/big-number.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/home/marco/dev/big-number'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /home/marco/dev/big-number/big-number.csproj
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.EditorConfigWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 200
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/marco/dev/big-number' on host 9016.
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/home/marco/dev/big-number/big-number.csproj'.
/home/marco/dev/big-number/big-number.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.  /home/marco/dev/big-number/big-number.csproj
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject (System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, System.Object[] args) [0x00040] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProject[T1] (System.Boolean condition, System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00003] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1] (Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00000] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement]& projects, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult, System.Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError) [0x00254] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImports (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult) [0x00027] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].EvaluateImportElement (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement) [0x0000d] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].PerformDepthFirstPass (Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport) [0x000e6] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext) [0x0011c] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IEvaluatorData`4[P,I,M,D] data, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement root, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, System.Int32 maxNodeCount, Microsoft.Build.Collections.PropertyDictionary`1[T] environmentProperties, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IItemFactory`2[S,T] itemFactory, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCache projectRootElementCache, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, System.Int32 submissionId, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext, System.Boolean interactive) [0x0002f] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x0005e] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00035] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00000] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00007] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00126] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00093] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection) [0x00000] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion) [0x000f7] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.String toolsVersion) [0x00000] in <b695b16788dd418cbe8b4d98f7a92ff3>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore (System.String filePath) [0x0003f] in <d71b11425cc74bd5a2cb9780240c3208>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject (System.String filePath) [0x0000d] in <d71b11425cc74bd5a2cb9780240c3208>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load (System.String filePath, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader loader) [0x00015] in <d71b11425cc74bd5a2cb9780240c3208>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager+<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<LoadProject>b__0 () [0x00000] in <d71b11425cc74bd5a2cb9780240c3208>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`1[System.ValueTuple`3[OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo,System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[OmniSharp.MSBuild.Logging.MSBuildDiagnostic],OmniSharp.MSBuild.Notification.ProjectLoadedEventArgs]].invoke_TResult()
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject (System.String projectFilePath, System.Func`1[TResult] loader) [0x0001b] in <d71b11425cc74bd5a2cb9780240c3208>:0 

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/marco/dev/big-number/big-number.csproj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by adding a `omnisharp.json` file with following content:

```
{
    "MSBuild": {
        "UseLegacySdkResolver": true
    }
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3287#issuecomment-536180721)

Comment: where i can find thats file omnisharp.json ?

Comment: please don't provide a solution that raises another question

Comment: @mamenaware I don't see another question here. If the file ist not there, you need to create it...

Comment: Where should i add this file? omnisharp.json

Comment: It is a config file for OmniSharp, so you just add it in your project root.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the reasons why you get this error is, .vscode is missing in your project. The path where Omnisharp is looking for the .Net SDK version is wrong, this is because Omnisharp looks for the required SDK in the path where Visual Studio saves its resources. to resolve this, update your visual studio so that it has the latest SDK version you are working with. and this should resolve the error and the project you're running on Visual Studio code will have the.VSCode folder.

To update Visual Studio, Open Visual Studio and select help on the top menu, look for "check for update" and then update.

IF you already did all this then, a simple Vs Code restart MAY be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seem to have done it for me
code -> preferences -> settings -> click this

;/ wish i had at least 10 reputation  to post a picture here but it's the first icon in the top right looks like a lil piece of paper.

Then..

copy pasta this into settings.json

```
{
  "explorer.compactFolders": false,
  "update.mode": "none",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "omnisharp.path": "latest",
  "omnisharp.monoPath": "auto",
  "csharp.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "[csharp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"
  },
  "[xml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "DotJoshJohnson.xml"
  },

  "settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": [],
  "window.zoomLevel": 0
}
```

that ^

```
"[csharp]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-dotnettools.csharp"
  },
  "[xml]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "DotJoshJohnson.xml"
  },
```

but i think this is what did the trick for me ^ specifically the [csharp]

Answer (score -1):

From reviewing the startup log, I saw a message that says I need .NET Developer Pack 4.7.1.

Downloading and Installing the .NET Framework 4.7.1 (Developer Pack) from https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/install/guide-for-developers solved the problem for me.