# OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager Attempted to update project that is not loaded csproj

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, omnisharp

I am trying to start a very small initial project in `Visual Studio Code` `C#`.
My OS is `Ubuntu-18.04`

I have node version `v12.15.0`

`npm` version `6.13.4`

Visual Code version `1.42.0`

I have installed `sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1` and installation was successful. Installation procedure comes from [offical instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-manager-ubuntu-1804) for `Ubuntu-18.04`

1) `wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb`

2) Installation of below as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1
```

This is the result of the `dotnet --info` below:

```
emanuele@pc:~$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.1.102
 Commit:    573d158fea

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.102/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.1.2
  Commit:  916b5cba26

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.1.102 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.2 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

**Installation is successfull** as final result.

I went on Visual Studio and created a new project typing:

1) `sudo npm install -g yo bower grunt-cli gulp generator-aspnet`

2) `yo aspnet` and correctly received welcome as shown below and chose **Web Application** as I would like to use a `google-drive API` approach as deplyable application in the future:

[image: welcome]

Instruction are available as shwn below, but when I `dotnet run` or `sudo dotnet run` I receive the following message:

[image: run]

Which Iam also reporting in case someone wants to copy/paste:

```
A compatible installed .NET Core SDK for global.json version [1.0.0-rc4-004771] from [/home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc/dredge-doc/global.json] was not found
Install the [1.0.0-rc4-004771] .NET Core SDK or update [/home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc/dredge-doc/global.json] with an installed .NET Core SDK:
  3.1.102 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
```

Below is the result of the output log:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 2/21/2020, 10:15:31 AM
    Target: /home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: /home/emanuele/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.12/.omnisharp/1.34.13/run
    PID: 13881

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on ubuntu 18.4 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 16.4 - "/home/emanuele/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.12/.omnisharp/1.34.13/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/home/emanuele/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.12/.omnisharp/1.34.13/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.dll'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.4 - "/home/emanuele/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.12/.omnisharp/1.34.13/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            MSBuildToolsPath = /home/emanuele/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.12/.omnisharp/1.34.13/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
            CscToolPath = /home/emanuele/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.12/.omnisharp/1.34.13/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
            BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = /home/emanuele/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.12/.omnisharp/1.34.13/omnisharp/.msbuild
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '/home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in '/home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc/dredge-doc/dredge-doc.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.ImplementTypeWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 110
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.EditorConfigWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 200
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc' on host 12704.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc/dredge-doc/dredge-doc.csproj
A compatible installed .NET Core SDK for global.json version [1.0.0-rc4-004771] from [/home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc/dredge-doc/global.json] was not found
Install the [1.0.0-rc4-004771] .NET Core SDK or update [/home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc/dredge-doc/global.json] with an installed .NET Core SDK:
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc/dredge-doc/dredge-doc.csproj'.
/home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc/dredge-doc/dredge-doc.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.  /home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc/dredge-doc/dredge-doc.csproj
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject (System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, System.Object[] args) [0x00040] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProject[T1] (System.Boolean condition, System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00003] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1] (Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00000] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement]& projects, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult, System.Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError) [0x00254] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImports (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult) [0x00027] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].EvaluateImportElement (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement) [0x0000d] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].PerformDepthFirstPass (Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport) [0x000e6] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext) [0x0014c] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IEvaluatorData`4[P,I,M,D] data, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement root, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, System.Int32 maxNodeCount, Microsoft.Build.Collections.PropertyDictionary`1[T] environmentProperties, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IItemFactory`2[S,T] itemFactory, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, System.Int32 submissionId, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext, System.Boolean interactive) [0x00044] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.Reevaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00063] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00035] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00000] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00007] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project+ProjectImpl.Initialize (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x0012b] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00075] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection) [0x00000] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion) [0x000f7] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.String toolsVersion) [0x00000] in <d7593966a5ec48e0baa47768c52e35a5>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore (System.String filePath) [0x0003f] in <274bc1b8e17a461caeeca97c1d1fc005>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject (System.String filePath) [0x0000d] in <274bc1b8e17a461caeeca97c1d1fc005>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load (System.String filePath, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader loader) [0x00015] in <274bc1b8e17a461caeeca97c1d1fc005>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager+<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<LoadProject>b__0 () [0x00000] in <274bc1b8e17a461caeeca97c1d1fc005>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`1[System.ValueTuple`3[OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo,System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[OmniSharp.MSBuild.Logging.MSBuildDiagnostic],OmniSharp.MSBuild.Notification.ProjectLoadedEventArgs]].invoke_TResult()
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject (System.String projectFilePath, System.Func`1[TResult] loader) [0x0001b] in <274bc1b8e17a461caeeca97c1d1fc005>:0 

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/emanuele/Desktop/dredge-doc/dredge-doc/dredge-doc.csproj
```

Posts I used in order to help me trying to solve the problems are:

1) [fail-omnisharp-msbuild-projectmanager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59260070/fail-omnisharp-msbuild-projectmanager)

2) [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59157254/omnisharp-msbuild-projectmanager-failed-to-load-project-on-linux) as my OS is also `Ubuntu-18.04` but it does not seems to me a doable solution because it required a manual installation of a file. I am not sure this is the right procedure to follow.

3) [This is useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55535177/omnisharp-msbuild-projectmanager-attempted-to-update-project-that-is-not-loaded) however the user used Windows, so I am not sure if that could also be a fixable solution

If anyone had the same problem I have, thanks for providing guidance to solving this issue.